# Sharepoint configuration - create new server farm System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: 2010, configuration

Getting the below error:

> Failed to create the configuration database.
>
> An execption of type System.InvalidOperationException was thrown. Additional exception >information: An error occurred while getting information about the user  at >server DOMAIN_SERVER>: Access is denied.

I have used 3 different Domain users 3 different times to try to create this and I am still getting the same error.

Points to note:

- All domain users used were part of Administrator group in DB server machine.
- All domain users used also have access to SQL server with server roles: securityadmin, serveradmin, setupadmin, sysadmin.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is in the system registry FIPS is enabled.
In the registry there are three keys which are related to FIPS.

1. HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\LSA\FipsAlgorithm
2. HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\Control\LSA\FipsAlgorithm
3. HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA\FipsAlgorithm

Set the value for all the keys as "0" to disable FIPS.

Then re-run the configuring wizard after deleting the created tables related to SharePoint in the SQL Server Database.

It works for me and configuration was completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced with the same issue. After some investigation I've found that we need to login to server with the same domain account which we've showed on Share point Product Configuration Wizard.